# What's the maximum number of textures per frame

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit

I have a javascript game that I want to run on iOS. The javascript sends number of images to be drawn and their positions. I used SpriteKit to draw the images, so I am creating SKTexture from the image name and add it to the parent node.

The problem is that I am drawing 30 textures/frame. The frame rate is very slow on iPad3 (it works well on iPhone 5s). I notice creating one texture takes 0.178 second, while loading it from a dictionary takes around 0.0036 second.

So for 30 textures, updating one frame will take 0.1 second, while I need it to be 0.016 to  get 60 fps.

Is 30 textures per frame, is too much? what is the alternative?

Is Sprite the correct framework to use? 
I want to target iOS7, iOS8.

**Edit:**
Here's how I get textures

```
 func getTexture(imageNamed: String) -> SKTexture?{
    if let texture = cache.getObject(imageNamed) {
        return texture
    }else {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed)
        cache.putObject(texture, forName: imageNamed)
        return texture
    }
}
```

Then I add it to SpriteKit's node:

```
if let texture = getTexture(imageName) {

     let imageNode = SKSpriteNode(texture:texture)
     imageNode.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 1)
     imageNode.position = CGPoint(x:x, y:y)

     parentNode!.addChild(imageNode)
}
```

So the above code, will create the texture once and add it to a cache, and next time it will be required, it will be brought from the cache. Currently I am not releasing textures from the cache, because it has small number of textures.

At the next update I remove all children from the parentNode, and add textures again based on new positions.

I don't want to add Sprite's actions, because we already have the game in javascript and we don't want to rewrite for iOS, so we just want to add a layer between js and iOS.

Comment: Drawing 30 SKSpriteNodes in a frame is usually not a problem. I have a game in the AppStore drawing hundreds of SKSpriteNodes. Why don't you load your 30 SKSpriteNodes once during launch of your App and move the Nodes in each update cycle? And why do you use JavaScript to calculate the 30 (ImageNumber, xPosition, yPosition) triplets? At least, this is how I understood it.

Comment: Are you "creating" these textures each frame or just "drawing" them. There's quite a significant difference between the two. There's just not enough information here to help you efficiently. If you are "creating" 30 images each frame, then maybe you need to think about pooling. Just not really clear what you are actually doing as you use the words draw/create at different points. Maybe add some code to specify what you are actually doing.

Comment: As Nero said, drawing 30 `SKSpriteNode`s each frame is not an issue. The devil is likely in the details here.

Comment: I added code, hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still not enough information in the question to determine where exactly the problem is, but here are a few tips where you definitely can improve your concept.

> At the next update I remove all children from the parentNode, and add textures again based on new positions.

I am not 100% sure, but chances are high that this is one of your bottlenecks. This is not how a SpriteKit-based game should be designed. Usually one should:

- Add necessary sprites to the scene graph once they are supposed to become visible
- Move objects somehow that are supposed to move (not remove and re-add)
- Remove nodes when they are supposed to disappear permanently
- Hide nodes if they only disappear shortly (there is a flag for this)

So, instead of clearing the whole scene graph you should move your objects around. This does not necessarily mean that you have to use SKActions, but it is recommended to do so, as they are optimized for running animations like moving stuff around. You can also change the `position` attribute of any SKNode during your update step. Maybe this is already enough to allow for 30 or even 60 fps. And by the way, it is now always necessary to run a game at 60 fps. If everything moves slowly, 30 fps may be enough.

> So the above code, will create the texture once and add it to a cache, and next time it will be required, it will be brought from the cache. Currently I am not releasing textures from the cache, because it has small number of textures.

Maybe you can also improve this by using texture atlases. This reduces the number of actual textures in memory, and you can still load the respective textures by addressing their file names.

> I don't want to add Sprite's actions, because we already have the game in javascript and we don't want to rewrite for iOS, so we just want to add a layer between js and iOS.

I have never combined a SpriteKit game with JavaScript being responsible for game logic. I can't tell how much of an impact that is. But if you can calculate the positions of each Sprite for each frame just move the Sprites to their respective positions – by changing their positions, not by re-adding everything to the scene graph.

The JavaScript may still be the bottleneck. If the above changes are not sufficient for reaching 30 or 60 fps, maybe check whether or not your JS runs fast enough on an iPad/iPhone. There probably is a difference in speed between running JS on a Mac/PC and iPhone/iPad.

Comment: keeping nodes doesn't affect the performance. Now it is not redrawing the scene in every update call and it has 30 fps. and the game looks good at iOS8 for both iPhone 5s and iPad 3 but not iOS7

Comment: We used Ejecta, it does what we exactly wants and the performance is great.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted because it has useful tips developers using Sprite. Thanks